# SQL Server 2008 performance tuning (T-SQL) multiple LEFT JOIN table vs. view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 20+ supporting tables set up the following way

```
[common_column1, common_column2, unique_column]
```

I need to come up with a combined table or a view that would be set up like this

```
[common_column1, common_column2, 
 table1_unique_column, table2_unique_column, table3_unique_column, etc...]
```

I have 6 million + records in every supporting table. My combined table / view creation query looks like this:

```
select 
   a.common_column1, a.common_column2, a.unique_column, b.unique_column, 
   c.unique_column, d....  
into combined_table  
from table1 as a   
left join table2 as b on (a.common_column1 = b.common_column1 and a.common_column2 = b.common_column2)  
left join table3 as c on (a.common_column1 = c.common_column1 and a.common_column2 = c.common_column2)  
left join table4 as d ...`
```

My primary object is to have the best read performance on the combined table / view, which I will be querying multiple times on all fields. Could you, please, suggest what would be better: to create a combined table and put indexes onto its every column or to put indexes onto every common column of every supporting table and then create a combined view? Or is there some other way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had no `LEFT JOIN`, you could investigate the **indexed views** - but since you those left joins, those are out of the question.

Using `LEFT JOIN` is messy and costly - and there's really not much "magic" to speeding this up.

Just make sure to have an index on each and every **foreign key column(s)** in the child tables that you use in your joins, and on your columns in the `WHERE` clause(s) - that's about all you can do, I'm afraid...

But be aware: too many indices can be worse than no indices at all... pick them carefully!

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I think I could explore ways to tweak the data in child tables to get rid of LEFT JOINS and substitute them with INNER JOINS in the combined view/table. If I change to INNER JOINS, do you think that a combined indexed view would read slower or faster than a combined table with all the records from child tables inserted into it?

Comment: @Greg Kostrikin: if you could create an indexed view, that would typically be orders of magnitudes faster than regular views - definitely worth looking into!

Comment: would you say, though, that read performance of an indexed view is worse or better than that of a table furnished with the same columns as the view? I'm under impression that it could be better in my case to create a combined table by joining all the child tables once as opposed to creating a view that would have to perform join opperation every time I query it.

Comment: @Greg Kostrikin: An indexed view is something like a "computed table" - the rows are **stored on disk** (just like with a table). So it should be almost as fast as a regular table. And yes, you can even put indices on columns in an indexed view! The plus side is: SQL Server takes care of keeping the rows up to date when the underlying tables change - you have nothing to do at all - just select from that indexed view!

Comment: Thanks! INNER JOINs and an indexed view should do the trick in my case then.

Answer (score 0):

A view is the same as a select - it will have no affect on performance but they are often easier to manage.
As for whether a combined table will be faster, it's hard to tell without seeing the query you are trying to run.
BTW, indexing every column is unlikely to be useful.  Indexing join columns is likely.  Indexing columns used in the "where" clause might help too.
Why don't you post your query and we'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Create a covering index in each of the supporting tables:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_b_1_2_unique ON b (common_column1, common_column2) INCLUDE (unique_column)
```

Note that for this query to be feasible, the common columns should also be almost unique.

If you have but `2` duplicates on `(common_column1, common_column2)` in each of the tables, it will return you `1048576` records for each pair in `a`.

Could you please reveal you model a little more? Are you sure you need joins, not unions?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My common_column1 is varchar with labels like ('a', 'ab', 'ac') and my common_column2 is int array (1:2600). There could be repeated non-unique labels in common_column1 and repeated non-unique numbers in common_column2. However, a combination of label from common_column1 and a number from common_column2 is always unique. Do you think that the covering index that you're proposing is better than a clustered index on common_column1 and a non-clustered index on common_column2 for each supporting table?